# What is the best way to store a set of strings

Tags: java, android, sdk, local-storage, storage

So I have a set of strings:

```
public Set<String> favs = new HashSet<>();
```

Which I add to in the activity later. However I want to be able to read and write these strings from other activities using just one source for all the data I've added a little graphic to try and explain what I mean better. What would be the best way to store my individual strings in this manner?

I would want the data to persist on closing the app.
At a guess there would be a maximum of about 30 items.
The data would come internally from entered data.

[image]

Comment: It would depend on how you would like to read and write said strings since you would probably need to look into race conditions.

Comment: mandatory documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: Shared Preferences would be the easiest but not suited for large values. Consider using Internal Storage for larger values. See https://github.com/hendraanggrian/android-quickstore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

consider using shared preference.

```
  public void setValue(Set<String> stringSet) {
        getSharedPreferences(getClass().getSimpleName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putStringSet("key",stringSet).comit();
    }
```

Comment: `commit` or `apply` anybody?